# What is the right way to add element in Arraylist from more than one methods?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to add element in my arraylist from different method. But i want to know that its a right way to go ahead, if not plaase suggest best way of it

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    List<String>links=new ArrayList<>();
    addLinkFromServerOne(links);
    return view;
}

private void addLinkFromServerOne(final List<String> links)
{
    ...
    String link=".....";
    links.add(link);

    addLinkFromServerTwo(links);
}

private void addLinkFromServerTwo(final List<String> links)
{
    ...
    String link=".....";
    links.add(links);
    checkStatus(links);
}

private void checkStatus(links)
{
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), String.valueOf(links.size()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it is quite good practice to wrap interactions with collections inside of class storing it. Also, that is not good practice to expose collections to other classes. That might be dangerous and confusing further because you can not only add but also remove elements from list. And that means inconsistent data.

Long story short: you are doing great!

Comment: thanx @samaromku

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are doing anything more than that (for example, if that methods are on a different thread (Async)), that is correct.

Comment: My english is weak please try to tell in simple words